# java.lang.IllegalStateException In clustered environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, hazelcast, spring-session

I have web application with spring, spring security, spring session with hazelcast.
It is running on clustered environment.
I see this exception in logs from time to time but can't reproduce it in locally.
It looks like some itercetptor or filter does not work correctly.
Any suggestion how to find the cause of the problem?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:328) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.java:122) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:436) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:379) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:176) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.35]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.35]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.35]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>xxxx</display-name>
  <description>xxxx</description>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>ch.qos.logback.classic.selector.servlet.ContextDetachingSCL</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>com.xxxxx.services.authentication.xxxxApplicationContextInitializer</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>  
  <filter>
    <filter-name>LoggerContextFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>ch.qos.logback.classic.selector.servlet.LoggerContextFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>PageExpiryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.xxxxx.web.filters.PageExpiryFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>sessionIpAddressSecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoggerContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PageExpiryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sessionIpAddressSecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>yyyy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>yyyy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error-page</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/resourceNotFound</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/resourceNotFound</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/resourceNotFound</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/notAuthorized</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/notAuthorized</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/serverError</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>503</error-code>
    <location>/serverError</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>504</error-code>
    <location>/serverError</location>
  </error-page>
  <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>http://xx.xx.xxx.com/tlds/functions</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/review.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
  </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

PageExpiryFilter:

```
public class PageExpiryFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
private static final int HOUR_TO_MINUTE = 60;
private static final int DAY_TO_MINUTE = 60 * 24;
private static final int MONTH_TO_MINUTE = 60 * 24 * 30;
private static final int WEEK_TO_MINUTE = 60 * 24 * 7;

private PageExpiryFilterPropertiesLoader loader = new PageExpiryFilterPropertiesLoader();

private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)(m|M|h|d|w)$");
private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

private Map<String, Integer> pathRegex;

@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse && request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        final String path = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
        final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        setResponseHeader(path, httpServletResponse);
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private void setResponseHeader(final String path, final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    String expiryDate;
    for (final String regex : pathRegex.keySet()) {
        if (path.matches(regex)) {
            final Integer age = pathRegex.get(regex);
            expiryDate = createExpiryDate(age);
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Expires", expiryDate);
        }
    }
}

private String createExpiryDate(final Integer age) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, age);
    return dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
}

@Override
public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    pathRegex = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    Properties properties = loader.loadProperties("/expires.properties");
    populatePathRegex(properties);
}

private void populatePathRegex(final Properties properties) {
    for (Entry<Object, Object> property : properties.entrySet()) {
        Integer expirationInMinutes = getExpirationInMinutes(((String) property.getValue()).trim());
        pathRegex.put((String) property.getKey(), expirationInMinutes);
    }
}

private Integer getExpirationInMinutes(final String value) {
    Integer minutes = 0;
    if (value != null && value.length() != 0) {
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            final int val = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
            final String denomination = matcher.group(2);
            minutes = calculateMinutes(val, denomination);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid pattern '" + value + "'" + " for '" + value
                    + "'. Valid patterns are '2m' for 2 minutes, '10h' for 10 hours, '1d' for 1 day, '1w' for 1 week, '1M' for 1 month");
        }
    }
    return minutes;
}

private Integer calculateMinutes(final int val, final String denomination) {
    int factor;
    if ("m".equals(denomination)) {
        factor = 1;
    } else if ("h".equals(denomination)) {
        factor = HOUR_TO_MINUTE;
    } else if ("d".equals(denomination)) {
        factor = DAY_TO_MINUTE;
    } else if ("M".equals(denomination)) {
        factor = MONTH_TO_MINUTE;
    } else {
        factor = WEEK_TO_MINUTE;
    }
    return val * factor;
}

public void setLoader(final PageExpiryFilterPropertiesLoader loader) {
    this.loader = loader;
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using the async servlet API? Are any of the filters that you've configured using the async API?

Comment: No I am not using any async API.

Comment: Can you post your web.xml?

Comment: What does PageExpiryFilter do?  Are you calling `chain.doFilter` after rendering a response within that filter?

Comment: The filter just sut up the "Expires" key in the response header.